# I need a solution to pick the right rate from product sheet and paste the filtered rate to expected rate result sheet

Tags: excel

```
Sheet 1 (Products) contains different rate combinations.
```

[image].

```
Sheet 2 (ExpectedResult) contain one combination which should pull the rate from products sheet based on boundary conditions check
```

[image][2].

```
I am entering the a value in expected rate sheet with conditions like
Amount has 888,
Fundsrequiredate =10,
LTV = 0.66,
Postal Code = H,
Expected Rate should be = 0.28 (picked from product sheet)

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJY6U.png][3]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjQr1.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBMae.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJY6U.png
Can anyone help me with macro logic to pick the rates based the input given in expected result sheet. Here I have given only one conditions. There can be many rows.
```

Comment: Have you considered vlookup() or index() with match() ? Don’t have rime to chase all your images...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.  You should change the format of your input table so that each quantity or value which has a minimum and a maximum shows them separately, not joined together.  Once you do this (as per the screenshot below), it's a simple matter of using a `SUMPRODUCT` formula:

[image]